# Getting input name from dijit widget

Tags: input, dojo

I'm creating dijit widget from input:

```html
<input name="serviceName" type="text"/>
```

```javascript
input = new ValidationTextBox({required: true}, query('[name=serviceName]')[0])
```

I have a lot of inputs and I want to batch-process them, giving them to separate function.

The problem is, that I can't find in docs, how to get the input name back from widget (which can be also Select, DateBox etc., neither I can find that property inspecting element in Firebug

```javascript
function processInput(input) {
   var inputName = ???
}
```

I've tried `input.name` and `input.get('name'),` but they are returning undefined.

Answer (score 1):

When instantiating your widget programmatically, properties are usually not copied. It's only when you use declarative markup that these properties are copied. This means that the `name` property is not copied from your original input node, so it's in fact empty.

When creating your `ValidationTextBox`, just provide the `name` property like the example below:

```
var inputNode = query('[name=serviceName]')[0];
var input = new ValidationTextBox({
    required: true,
    name: inputNode.name
}, inputNode);
```

You can then retrieve the name with either `input.name` or `input.get('name')`.

I also made an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/BPDSY/).